# ExtJS Combobox with Checkbox

Tags: extjs

I want to design combo with checkboxes(display checkboxes along with dispalyfield)
i tried lovcomb, but not getting
is there any alternative for this or how to use lovcombo for multiple section

Thanks in advance

Comment: post some code and we may be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method (with out checkboxes):
http://technomedia.co.uk/SuperBoxSelect/examples3.html